# How to redirect multiple apps in Nginx reverse proxy on docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running nginx reverse proxy on docker together with two React.js apps. I want to make it so that both apps are accessible via the same port by just adding /app1 or /app2. When I had only http, it worked but now i added ssl and it does not work.

Here is my default.conf

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;
    if ($scheme = http) {
           return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
  
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl; # 'ssl' parameter tells NGINX to decrypt the traffic
    server_name         xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key xxx.xxx.xxx.xx-key.pem;

  ssi on;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  location /app1 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://app1:5000;

      # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location /app2 {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://app2:5000;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }


}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
   version: "3.1"

services: 
  app1:
    stdin_open: true
    build: app1/app1
    networks:
      - local-network
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - PORT=5000
      
  app2:
    stdin_open: true
    build: app2/app2
    networks:
      - local-network
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - PORT=5000

  micro-frontend-nginx:
    container_name: micro-frontend-nginx
    build: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./assets:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - local-network
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2

networks:
  local-network:
```

Those are the files where I specify any ports. Could you tell me why it fails to redirect the apps properly?

UPDATE:

ERROR LOG:

> 2020/10/30 12:40:30 [error] 7#7: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL:
> error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol)
> while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.160.1, server:
> 192.168.178.94, request: "GET /app2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.160.2:5000/app2", host: "192.168.178.94"

Comment: In the `proxy_pass` statements, you've specified http:// rather than https:// - could this be the problem? If that failis to fix, could you add some log output to help establish where the problem is?

Comment: I did it and it failed too. I am still new to reverse proxies so could you tell me where I can find the log output?

Comment: It gives me Bad Gateaway.

Comment: I added the error log

Comment: Have you considered [jwilder's automated nginx proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)? - with it set up is simple and you don't need to worry about nginx configuration.